# Como filtrar os ids contidos em uma tabela com os valores contidos em um array - Laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-eloquent, laravel-blade, laravel-4

Bom dia. Estou com o seguinte "problema"/dúvida:

Tenho um **formulário** que contém alguns **selects**, dentre estes selects existem alguns que são **multiselects**, quando eu submeto o meu formulário os valores selecionados nestes multiselects são armazanados em um **array** próprio para o mesmos. No meu **Controller** faço a requisição deste array e o salvo em uma **variável**, posteriormente faço um **filtro** com os valores contidos nesta varável com os **ids** de uma **tabela x**, o resultado deste filtro é um **array de objetos** que estarei ultilizando na minha view.

O meu grande problema está sendo na forma de **filtrar** e **salvar** estes dados no novo **array**. Pelo que eu pude perceber, o meu método está filtrando pelo número do **indíce** do array de obejtos e não pelo **id** contido em cada um dos **arrays**. **Como eu cheguei à esta conclusão?** Selecionei as três opções que estão disponíveis no meu **multiselect** e submeti o **formulário**. Quando eu uso o meu método **filter** e dou um **dd** na váriavel **$resultStamps**, o resultado é que a variável contém apenas os arrays de id **2** e **3**. Sendo que o array de id **1** contido no indíce **0** não aparece.

Eu li a documentção do **Laravel** sobre **Collections** e o método **filter** foi o que me paraceu mais adequado para o que eu preciso. Porém, pode ser que tenha outro que seja mais adequado e eu não tenha percebido.

***Trecho de código do meu formulário:***

```
<div class="mb-3">
    <label for="" class="form-label">Selo:
        <span style="color: red; font-size: 12px;">*</span>
    </label>
    <select class="js-example-basic-multiple form-control" name="stamp[]" multiple="multiple">>
        @foreach ($stamps as $stamp)
            <option value="{{ $stamp->id }}">
                {{ $stamp->descricao }}</option>
        @endforeach
    </select>
</div>
```

***Trecho de código do meu Controller:***

```
$stamp = $request->input('stamp');
 
$stamps = Stamp::get();

$resultStamps = $stamps->filter(function ($value, $stamp){
    return $value->id = $stamp;
});

$resultStamps->all());
```

O que tente fazer no código acima foi usar o método filter para filtrar os valores contidos na tabela **Stamps** e os valores contidos no meu array **Stamp**, se o valor do **id** contido em um dos arrays da tabela **Stamps** for igual a um dos **valores** contidos no array **Stamp** ele me retorna um novo array do resultado deste filtro.

[Imagem do meu Array Stamp, com os valores vindo do meu formulário (estes valores correspondem aos ids selecionados)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfTXR.png)

[Imagem do resultado do meu filter, observe que os valores das chaves estão como se fosse um string e não um int](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UsBmE.png)

[Imagem da minha Tabela Stamps](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z1mkt.png)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Lendo/relendo a documentação do ***Laravel*** sobre ***Collections*** e após vários testes consegui encontrar o que eu procurava. O método que resolveu o meu problema é o **whereIn()**, o método whereIn remove os elementos da coleção que não possuem um valor de item especificado contido na matriz fornecida.

***Trecho de código:***

```
$stamp = $request->input('stamp'); // Armazenando os valores (ids) vindos do meu formulário na variável $stamp
$stamps = Stamp::whereIn('id', $stamp)->get(); // Ultilizando o método whereIn e armazenando os valores na variável $stamps

// Ou posso escrever desta forma, resultará na mesma coisa
$stamps = Stamp::whereIn('id', $request->stamp)->get();
```

**Obs:** São passados dois "parâmetros" no método whereIn, o primeiro é os ***ids*** contidos na minha tabela ***Stamp*** e o segundo é os ***valores (ids)*** contidos na minha variável ***$stamp***.

***Exemplo prático:***

```
// Supondo que estes sejam os ids que selecionei no meu multiselect
$stamp = [ 
    0 => "1"
    1 => "2"
]

// Supondo que esta seja a minha tabela ou collection
$stamps = [
    0 => App\Model...\Stamp{
        #attributes: array: [
            "id" => 1
        ]
    }
    1 => App\Model...\Stamp{
        #attributes: array: [
            "id" => 2
        ]
    }
    2 => App\Model...\Stamp{
        #attributes: array: [
            "id" => 3
        ]
    }
]

// O resultado que eu estarei obtendo usando o método whereIn, será:
$stamps = [
    0 => App\Model...\Stamp{
        #attributes: array: [
            "id" => 1
        ]
    }
    1 => App\Model...\Stamp{
        #attributes: array: [
            "id" => 2
        ]
    }
]
```